# Engine sounds like it's in 4th gear while it's in 5th gear, the revs stays normal

Tags: engine

Engine sounds like it's in 4th gear while it's in 5th gear, the revs stays normal, what could cause that?

Comment: What do you mean by "sounds like it's in 4th". When you shift from 4th to 5th, your RPM should DROP - (_that's normal_) . Where is the incongruity?

Comment: If the issue is just with the way the engine "sounds", the increased sound may be due to something like a pierced exhaust or compromised exhaust flange gasket.

Comment: @Zaid, good point.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I hope we can provide you some help :D We will need a little more information, starting with the year/make/model of the vehicle. Also, is it a manual or automatic? Please help explain what you are talking about a little better. We just want to understand so we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

If the engine is still revving as hard as it was in fourth it may be that your clutch is slipping and is due for replacement.